# c++ lower_bound for std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, lower-bound

I'm writing a test program to learn these two func: `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`. I previously found on the wiki that this function returns the first iterator that is no less than the parameter. But when I test with numbers not in the map, strange things happened,  when the minimum key in the map is 1, I use `lower_bound (0)` and feel like I should return an iterator with key 1. But it returned `mp.end()`.

The test program is:

```cpp
// C++ function for illustration
// map::lower_bound() function
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  // initialize container
  map<int, int, greater<int>> mp;

  // insert elements in random order
  mp.insert({2, 30});
  mp.insert({1, 10});
  mp.insert({5, 50});
  mp.insert({4, 40});
  for (auto it = mp.begin(); it != mp.end(); it++)
  {
    cout << (*it).first << " " << (*it).second << endl;
  }

  // when 2 is present
  auto it = mp.lower_bound(3);
  cout << "The lower bound of key 3 is ";
  cout << (*it).first << " " << (*it).second << endl;

  // when 3 is not present
  // points to next greater after 3
  it = mp.lower_bound(0);
  if (it == mp.end())
  {
    cout << "The lower bound of key 0 is ";
  }
  cout << (*it).first << " " << (*it).second << endl;

  // when 6 exceeds
  it = mp.lower_bound(6);
  if (it == mp.end())
  {
    cout << "The lower bound of key 6 is ";
  }
  cout << (*it).first << " " << (*it).second << endl;

  it = mp.lower_bound(1);
  auto next = std::next(it);
  cout << "The lower bound of key 1 is ";
  cout << (*it).first << " " << (*it).second << endl;
  cout << "The next of key 1 is ";
  cout << (*next).first << " " << (*next).second << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and this is what I got as output:

```
5 50

4 40

2 30

1 10

The lower bound of key 3 is 2 30

The lower bound of key 0 is 4 0

5 50

The lower bound of key 1 is 1 10

The next of key 1 is 4 0
```

I have no idea why lower bound of 0 is 4 0, shouldn't it be 1 10?

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;` - stop this madness.

Comment: It's because you use `greater<int>` when creating the map.  By default `std::map` uses `std::less`.  By using `std::greater` you have caused to map to sort the keys in reverse (descending) order.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: I strongly suggest you try a map with `std::less` first and only after you have wrapped your head around that should you try `std::greater`. Also what pptaszni said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your code has undefined behavior:

```
it = mp.lower_bound(0);

if (it == mp.end())
  cout << "The lower bound of key 0 is ";

cout << (*it).first << " " << (*it).second << endl;
```

When `it` equals to `mp.end()`, then you cannot dereference it. Change this to:

```
if (it != mp.end()) 
  cout << "The lower bound of key 0 is "
       << (*it).first << " " << (*it).second << endl;
```

and you will see that nothing is printed, since `mp.lower_bound(0)` actually returns `end()`.

Live demo (minimalized): https://godbolt.org/z/hdsK9j6aj

---

> shouldn't it be 1 10?

No, it shouldn't. `lower_bound(key)`:

> Returns iterator pointing to the first element that is **not less than** `key`.

But this *less than* relationship is evaluated **with respect to the provided comparator**, which is `std::greater` in your case. Then, you can *logically* transform this sentence into:

> Returns iterator pointing to the first element that is **not mathematically greater than** `key`.

And, since the map does not contain any key *mathematically-not-greater-than* zero, the end iterator is returned.